# Obtener saltos de linea de un textarea con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo un text area.

```
<textarea style="font-size:15px;text-align:left;width:500px;height:150px" class="control-label"  id="txtTextoTemplate">{{txtTextoTemplate}}</textarea>
```

Este texto, lo necesito para modificar un text que uso en conjunto con una libreria para enviar mails automaticamente.
Supongamos que en el text area escribo lo siguiente

```
hola
este es un
ejemplo
del error
```

Usando la siguiente la funcion en JS, obtengo el texto:

```
var TextoTemplate = document.getElementById('txtTextoTemplate').value;
```

y en el siguiente metodo hago llamado mi funcion de c#, enviando los parametros necesarios.

```
$scope.Guardar = function () {
    $scope.isViewLoadingGuardar = true;
    $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
    $scope.MostrarMensajeError = false;

    //Obtengo el texto del textArea
    var TextoTemplate = document.getElementById('txtTextoTemplate').value;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseURL + 'Configuracion/ModificarTemplate/?Id=' + $scope.Id + "&Texto=" + encodeURIComponent(TextoTemplate) + "&Nombre=" + $scope.lblNombreTemplate,
    }).success(function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            $scope.isViewLoadingGuardar = false;
            $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', '');
            $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
            $scope.MostrarMensajeError = false;

            $scope.volver();
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isViewLoadingGuardar = false;
        $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', '');
        alert(data);
        $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
        $scope.MostrarGrilla = false;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    });

};
```

pero lo que esta funcion me envía es 
"HolaEste es unEjemploDel error". Entonces como puedo obtener los saltos de linea para poder insertar el caracter "\n" en mi sql? El caracter "\n" son los saltos de linea.
Por C# no puedo, ya que al siguiente metodo

```
 public IHttpActionResult ModificarTemplate(int Id, string Texto, string Nombre)
    {
        try
        {
            //guardo el dato en la base.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //error al guardar
        }

    }
```

la variable Texto ya me llegue todo junto.

Comment: Estas mandando el texto en el query string, ya que estas usando method: 'POST' manda el texto como data.

Comment: Ahi abajo puse la respuesta que encontre en un ejemplo que no era referido a este. Pero explicame lo que quisiste decir, tal vez tambien se solucione de esa manera

Comment: tu codigo envia un post y pasa por parametro por GET

Answer (score 1):

Indagando en internet encontre que la agregando encodeURIComponent me traiga los caracteres tal cual el textbox. Me quedo de la siguiente manera

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseURL + 'Configuracion/ModificarTemplate/?Id=' + $scope.Id + "&Texto=" + encodeURIComponent(TextoTemplate) + "&Nombre=" + $scope.lblNombreTemplate,
    }).success(function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            $scope.isViewLoadingGuardar = false;
            $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', '');
            $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
            $scope.MostrarMensajeError = false;

            $scope.volver();
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.isViewLoadingGuardar = false;
        $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', '');
        alert(data);
        $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
        $scope.MostrarGrilla = false;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    });
```